# Understanding spring bin name "&amp;myBean"

Tags: java, spring

In one spring context I found that some bean references contains `&amp;` before bean name. I wonder what `&amp;` in the begin of spring name means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are references to FactoryBeans (i.e. to the factories themselves, as opposed to the objects that the factories produce).  From the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)

> When you need to ask a container for an actual `FactoryBean` instance itself, not the bean it produces, you preface the bean id with the ampersand symbol `&` (without quotes) when calling the `getBean()` method of the `ApplicationContext`. So for a given `FactoryBean` with an id of myBean, invoking `getBean("myBean")` on the container returns the product of the `FactoryBean`, and invoking `getBean("&myBean")` returns the `FactoryBean` instance itself.

Ampersands in XML need to be escaped as `&amp;` entity references, so if you wanted to declare a property value in XML which is a reference to a `FactoryBean` you'd need

```
<property name="someProperty" ref="&amp;myBean" />
```