# @Primary on Factory Beans

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, factory

The simplified version I have looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseDefaultConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSourceDefault(DatabaseConfigurationHelper databaseConfigurationHelper) {
    return ...;
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBeanDefault(DatabaseConfigurationHelper databaseConfigurationHelper, @Value("${datasource.default.cacheEnabled}") boolean cacheEnabled) throws Exception {
    return ...;
  }

}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseMaintenanceConfig {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSourceMaintenance(DatabaseConfigurationHelper databaseConfigurationHelper) {
    return ...;
  }

  @Bean
  public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBeanMaintenance(DatabaseConfigurationHelper databaseConfigurationHelper, @Value("${datasource.maintenance.cacheEnabled}") boolean cacheEnabled) throws Exception {
    return ...;
  }

}
```

The classes are very much the same, one uses `@Primary`. Now let's create two dummy beans:

```
@Configuration
public class CommonDatabaseConfig {

  @Bean
  public AtomicInteger a(SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean) {
    return new AtomicInteger();
  }

  @Bean
  public AtomicLong b(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new AtomicLong();
  }

}
```

While `b` works fine, `a` fails and claims that two beans were found:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method a in sjngm.CommonDatabaseConfig required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - &sqlSessionFactoryBeanDefault: defined by method 'sqlSessionFactoryBeanDefault' in class path resource [sjngm/DatabaseDefaultConfig.class]
    - &sqlSessionFactoryBeanMaintenance: defined by method 'sqlSessionFactoryBeanMaintenance' in class path resource [sjngm/DatabaseMaintenanceConfig.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Note that both beans start with a `&`. Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16834714/483113) and its answer it becomes clear that this is intended. However, that seems to break applying the `@Primary` as it fails in this area of Spring's `DefaultListableBeanFactory`:

```
protected boolean isPrimary(String beanName, Object beanInstance) {
    if (containsBeanDefinition(beanName)) {
        return getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(beanName).isPrimary();
    }
    BeanFactory parent = getParentBeanFactory();
    return (parent instanceof DefaultListableBeanFactory &&
            ((DefaultListableBeanFactory) parent).isPrimary(beanName, beanInstance));
}
```

`containsBeanDefinition()` in line 2 returns `false` because of the ampersand.

Now: Am I doing something wrong here? How can I fix this?

*This is Spring 4.3.9 (as part of Spring-Boot 1.5.4)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed within `spring-framework` PR [22711](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/22711).